# Adding Pop with attribute characteristics to features in Leaflet

Tags: java, html, leaflet, popup, gis

I need to show popup for GEOJSON data with its attributes.However,I don't have any idea on showing popup for GEOJSON data added through url of wfs.The geojson data is earthquake data added through the following url:-https://emidius.mi.ingv.it/services/italy/wfs/?service=wfs&version=2.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeNames=italy:CPTI_current&outputFormat=application/json.
Could someone help.
The code file that I am working is given below:-

```html
<html>
<head>
  <title>Creating mash-ups with Leaflet</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.css" integrity="sha512-xodZBNTC5n17Xt2atTPuE1HxjVMSvLVW9ocqUKLsCC5CXdbqCmblAshOMAS6/keqq/sMZMZ19scR4PsZChSR7A==" crossorigin="" />
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.js" integrity="sha512-XQoYMqMTK8LvdxXYG3nZ448hOEQiglfqkJs1NOQV44cWnUrBc8PkAOcXy20w0vlaXaVUearIOBhiXZ5V3ynxwA==" crossorigin=""></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://auth.airmap.com/js/keycloak.js"></script>
  <style>
    html,
    body {
      height: 100%;
      margin: 0;
    }
    
    #map {
      width: 1000px;
      height: 1000px;
    }
  </style>

  <head>

    <body>
      <div id="map"></div>
      <script>
        var map = L.map('map').setView([14.6361111, 42.1608333], 8);
        var wmsLayer = L.tileLayer.wms('https://www.gebco.net/data_and_products/gebco_web_services/web_map_service/mapserv?', {
          layers: 'GEBCO_LATEST_SUB_ICE_TOPO'
        }).addTo(map);

        var elevation;

        $.getJSON('https://demo.pygeoapi.io/master/collections/ogr_gpkg_poi/items?f=json', function(value) {
          var datalayer = L.geoJson(value, {
            onEachFeature: function(feature, featureLayer) {
              var lon = feature.geometry.coordinates[0];
              var lat = feature.geometry.coordinates[1];
              var city = feature.properties.name;

              $.ajax({
                url: 'https://api.airmap.com/elevation/v1/ele/?points=' + lat + ',' + lon +
                  '&units=metric& appid=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJjcmVkZW50aWFsX2lkIjoiY3JlZGVudGlhbHxwQUFNWlBxaEx2T2Q2cGZSR2JkMlhDQkdRcTdNIiwiYXBwbGljYXRpb25faWQiOiJhcHBsaWNhdGlvbnx3ZURHZ01oTldtek55c1A4S0xEdlRsQW5QTE0iLCJvcmdhbml6YXRpb25faWQiOiJkZXZlbG9wZXJ8MnpvYmI3eWh4ZVk0cWtDM1BSeDBaSEtNejIzOCIsImlhdCI6MTQ3MTM3OTc0Mn0.MeO0jt6holPt0jdPJvRJrTBi380WsbOPGCEO6u-tfSo',
                async: false,
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(json) {
                  elevation = json.data;
                }
              });
              featureLayer.bindPopup("City: " + city + "</br>Elevation: " + elevation + "metres");
            }
          }).addTo(map);
        });


var wfs_url = "https://emidius.mi.ingv.it/services/italy/wfs/?service=wfs&version=2.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeNames=italy:CPTI_current&outputFormat=application/json&CQL_FILTER=dwithin(geom,%20MULTIPOINT((41.701259 -7.5005), (40.655991 -7.917709), (40.200475 -8.419193),(40.198381 -7.639009),(40.087058 -8.290237),(39.369447 -9.391943),(38.443198 -9.100006),(38.448289 -9.130834),(32.748972 -16.697671)),%201400,%20kilometers)";
      $.getJSON(wfs_url).then((res) => {
        var layer = L.geoJson(res).addTo(map);

        map.fitBounds(layer.getBounds());
      });
      </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: It's the same way you did it for elevation and city for the other geojson